# I do not know how to fix the leak

Tags: iphone

How do I fix the leak here?

```
-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {   
if(searching){      
    return nil;
}

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tempArray addObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];
[tempArray addObject:@"A"];
[tempArray addObject:@"B"];
[tempArray addObject:@"C"];
[tempArray addObject:@"D"];
[tempArray addObject:@"E"];
[tempArray addObject:@"F"];
[tempArray addObject:@"G"];
[tempArray addObject:@"H"];
[tempArray addObject:@"I"];
[tempArray addObject:@"J"];
[tempArray addObject:@"K"];
[tempArray addObject:@"L"];
[tempArray addObject:@"M"];
[tempArray addObject:@"N"];
[tempArray addObject:@"O"];
[tempArray addObject:@"P"];
[tempArray addObject:@"Q"];
[tempArray addObject:@"R"];
[tempArray addObject:@"S"];
[tempArray addObject:@"T"];
[tempArray addObject:@"U"];
[tempArray addObject:@"V"];
[tempArray addObject:@"W"];
[tempArray addObject:@"X"];
[tempArray addObject:@"Y"];
[tempArray addObject:@"Z"];

return tempArray;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be returning an autoreleased object:

```
return [tempArray autorelease];
```

Comment: cheers, that fixed that specific problem.. now to fix the others. *sigh*

Answer (score -4):

When you get the temparray, release it when done by calling

```
[#<your var># release];
```

to solve your leak. Autorelease will work, but you will need to set a NSAutoRelease pool and drain it after you're done to prevent a de facto leak (as the only autorelease pool is in main() at the beginning, so the program will not release until the program quits anyway).

Comment: The main() autorelease pool is drain at each run loop, not at the end of the program.

Comment: yes, auto release is drained on the run loop. (or when the program needs it i believe)